# "getLogoAlt" not available for content section in Magento

Tags: magento

In Magento CE 1.5.1, **why is getLogoAlt not available for the content section though it is available for the header section**?

Inside the content section of the home page, my theme's *home.phtml* has

```
<h1 class="no-display"><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></h1>
```

which outputs as

```
<h1 class="no-display"></h1>
```

But *header.phtml*,

```
<h4><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" id="logo" style="background-image:url(<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>)"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong></a></h4>
```

properly outputs as

```
<h4><a href="http://mystore.com/" id="logo" style="background-image:url(http://mystore.com/skin/frontend/mytheme/orange/images/logo.png)"><strong>Buy widgets here!</strong></a></h4>
```

Puzzled...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "header section" is a block added with the following layout update XML

```
<block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
```

The block's type is `page/html_head`, which translated to the class `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Header`.  If you look at the class definition, you can see the `header.phtml` template  being set.

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Header.php
public function _construct()
{
    $this->setTemplate('page/html/header.phtml');
}
```

When you use `$this->someMethod()` from a template, you're calling a method on the template's block class.  Each template "belongs" to a block.  If we look at the header class again

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Header.php
public function getLogoAlt()
{
    if (empty($this->_data['logo_alt'])) {
        $this->_data['logo_alt'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/header/logo_alt');
    }
    return $this->_data['logo_alt'];
}
```

we can see the definition of `getLogoAlt`.

The other template you mentioned, `home.phtml`, is added with the following layout update xml

```
<block type="core/template" name="default_home_page" template="cms/default/home.phtml"/>
```

Its block is a `core/template` block, which translates to `Mage_Core_Block_Template`.  This block does **not** have a `getLogoAlt` method.  However, like all blocks, it does have Magento's magic getters and setters.  You can "set" and "get" data properties on Magento blocks like this

```
$this->setFooBar('setting a value for the foo_bar data property');
echo $this->getFooBar();
```

even if the block doesn't have those methods defined.  So, this means you can **call** `getLogoAlt` on any block without an error being thrown, but only the header block is going to return a value.  If you want that value in **any** template, you can just call

```
$logo_alt = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/header/logo_alt');
```

at the top of your template, and then use `$logo_alt` wherever you'd like.

Comment: Thank you for the very through answer and explanation!

Comment: Hi, Nice explanation. What would be the best way have this function available on other templates other than header?

Comment: Adding the functions to the `Mage_Core_Block_Text_List` would be bad I think?